# Sharding key, chunkSize and pre-splitting

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have set up a sharded cluster on a single machine, following the steps mentioned here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/A+Sample+Configuration+Session
But I don't understand the '--chunkSize' option:
`$ ./mongos --configdb localhost:20000 --chunkSize 1 > /tmp/mongos.log &`

With N shards, each shard is supposed to have 1/N number of documents, dividing the shard-key's range into N almost equal parts, right? This automatically fixes the chunkSize/shard-size. Which chunk is the above command then dealing with?
Also, there's provision to split a collection manually at a specific value of key and then migrate a chunk to any other shard you want. This can be done manually and is even handled by a 'balancer' automatically. Doesn't it clash with the sharding settings and confuse the config servers or they are reported about any such movement immediately?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be confusing a few things. The --chunkSize parameter sets the chunk size for the doing splits. The "settings" collection in the "config" database with _id "chunksize" to have a look at the current value, if set. The --chunkSize option will only set this value, or make changes to the system, if there is no value set already, otherwise it will be ignored.

The chunk size is the size in megabytes above which the system will keep chunk under. This is done in two places, 1) when writes pass through the mongos instances and 2) prior to moving chunks to another shard during balancing. As such it does not follow from the "data size / shard count" formula. Your example of 1Mb per chunk is almost always a bad idea.

You can indeed split and move chunks manually and although that might result in a less than ideal chunk distribution it will never confuse or break the config meta data and the balancer. The reason is relatively straightforward; the balancer uses the same commands and follows the same code paths. From MongoDB's perspective there is no significant difference between a balancer process splitting and moving chunks and you doing it.

There are a few valid use cases for manually splitting and moving chunks though. For example, you might want to do it manually to prepare a cluster for very high peak loads from a cold start -- pre-splitting. Typically you will write a script to do this, or load splits from a performance test which already worked well. Also, you may watch for hot chunks to split/move those chunks to move evenly distribute based on "load" as monitored from your application.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks! I think I get it now..Correct me if I'm wrong:
I was thinking that if there are N servers, then first 1/Nth part of the collection (=chunk1) will go to shard1, the second 1/Nth (=chunk2) will go to shard2 and so on.. When you said that there's no such "formula", I searched a bit more and found these links 
[MongoDB sharding, how does it rebalance when adding new nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575643/mongodb-sharding-how-does-it-rebalance-when-adding-new-nodes?rq=1)
[How to define sharding range for each shard in Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934092/how-to-define-sharding-range-for-each-shard-in-mongo?rq=1)
From the definition of "chunk" in the documentation, I think it is to be thought of as merely a unit of data migration. When we shard a collection among N servers, then the total no. of chunks is not necessarily N. And they need not be of equal size either. 
The maximum size of one chunk is either already set as a default (usually 64MB) in the settings collection of config database, or can be set manually by specifying a value using the --chunkSize parameter as shown in the above code. Depending on the values of the shard-key, one shard may have more chunks than the other. But MongoDB uses a balancer process that tries to distribute these chunks evenly among the shards. By even distribution, I mean it tends to split chunks and migrate them to other shards if they grow bigger than their limit or if one particular shard is getting heavily loaded. This can be done manually as well, by following the same set of commands that the balancer process uses.

Comment: Well, techincally speaking it doesn't try to balance the chunks, it tries to balance the shard keys across the shards. The end result is usually the same though.

Comment: Ok yeah..you mean when nodes enter or exit, the balancer migrates the chunks so that the key distrbution is even.

Comment: Well what I meant was that it balances based on shard key, not chunk amount. That's what allows it to balance correctly when there are hotspots in the shard key distribution (e.g. a lot of data for a limited range of shard key values)

Comment: The balancer balances based on the chunk distribution, not load nor size (count or amount of data) of data/chunks (although that should be roughly equivalent to the chunk distribution). If there is an imbalance (typically 8 or more) of chunks then it starts to move/migrate some. During that process it may split them up more.